# How to fix tkinter validation (using regex and vcmd)

Tags: python-3.x, validation, tkinter

This code is a snippet of a program. I tried to do a system that validate an input, only if input is one or more numbers (r"^\d+$"). But it doesn't work, i check on my tkinter book reference, but i didnt find errors. The way that i develop it is using a vcmd function, that pass the value ("%P"), calling a function that validate the value. When it run match method of regex module, if it match the value in pattern, it get True, otherwise False. If False i want that non-numerical text wont be displayed in Entry widget, if True i want that numerical text will be displayed in Entry widget. Moreover it doesnt run invalidcommand function, and i tried to see how many time the validating function is run (only the first time).

```
import tkinter
import re as regex
from electronic_formulas import Electronic


class App(tkinter.Tk):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.var_r1 = tkinter.DoubleVar()
    self.var_r2 = tkinter.DoubleVar()

    self.pattern = regex.compile(r"^[0-9]+$")
    vcmd = (self.register(self.validating_values), "%P")

    self.frame_left = tkinter.Frame(self)
    self.frame_left.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
    self.frame_right = tkinter.Frame(self)
    self.frame_right.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

    self.entry_r1 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame_left, textvariable=self.var_r1, validate="key",
                                  validatecommand=vcmd, invalidcommand=lambda: print("Error"))
    self.entry_r1.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)

    self.entry_r2 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame_left, textvariable=self.var_r2, validate="key",
                                  validatecommand=vcmd, invalidcommand=lambda: print("Error"))
    self.entry_r2.pack(side=tkinter.TOP)

    self.var_r1.set("")
    self.var_r2.set("")

def validating_values(self, value):
    return self.pattern.match(value) is not None


app = App()

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.mainloop()
```

No tcl errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- you've set the value to be a `DoubleVar`, but then you don't allow a decimal point.
- your validation function doesn't allow an empty string but then you set the value to an empty string.

This is what the canonical [tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7) says about mixing `validatecommand` with `textvariable`:

> In general, the textVariable and validateCommand can be dangerous to mix. Any problems have been overcome so that using the validateCommand will not interfere with the traditional behavior of the entry widget. Using the textVariable for read-only purposes will never cause problems. The danger comes when you try set the textVariable to something that the validateCommand would not accept, which causes validate to become none (the invalidCommand will not be triggered). The same happens when an error occurs evaluating the validateCommand.

You are doing exactly that: setting the textvariable to something that the validatecommand would not accept. As a consequence, the `validate` option is set to `None`.

Comment: Ok thank you @Bryan Oakley. Now i set regex pattern with ^[\d. ]$ and DoubleVar. It works. You explain me that this way is dangerous, so should i use this mix? What do you suggest? You tell me about readonly, can you explain me more? I know what is it, but i dont know how to use it in this specific case (how can i set it?)

Comment: @Riccardo: personally, I suggest _not_ using `textvariable` at all. You can get and set the value of an entry widget without it. You're just adding extra complexity with no extra value.